# Proving that there are no overlapping sub-problems?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I just got the following interview question:

```
Given a list of float numbers, insert “+”, “-”, “*” or “/” between each consecutive pair of numbers to find the maximum value you can get. For simplicity, assume that all operators are of equal precedence order and evaluation happens from left to right.

Example:
(1, 12, 3) -> 1 + 12 * 3  = 39
```

If we built a recursive solution, we would find that we would get an O(4^N) solution. I tried to find overlapping sub-problems (to increase the efficiency of this algorithm) and wasn't able to find any overlapping problems. The interviewer then told me that there wasn't any overlapping subsolutions.

How can we detect when there are overlapping solutions and when there isn't? I spent a lot of time trying to "force" subsolutions to appear and eventually the Interviewer told me that there wasn't any.

My current solution looks as follows:

```
def maximumNumber(array, current_value=None):

    if current_value is None:
       current_value = array[0]
       array = array[1:] 

    if len(array) == 0:
       return current_value

    return max(
        maximumNumber(array[1:], current_value * array[0]),
        maximumNumber(array[1:], current_value - array[0]),
        maximumNumber(array[1:], current_value / array[0]),
        maximumNumber(array[1:], current_value + array[0])
    )
```

Comment: can the float numbers be negative? (have a sign associated with them ? )

Comment: I must be missing something, because it seems like a simple heuristic would solve that problem.

Comment: @hatchet Does your heuristic find the answer `(59, 60, -0.000001) -> 59 - 60 / -0.000001  = 1000000.0`?

Comment: @Srini Yes, the float numbers can be negative.

Comment: @hatchet Yeah, you're right: there is a heuristic that can solve this. Personally, I didn't find that heuristic obvious at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for "overlapping subproblems" sounds like you're trying to do bottom up dynamic programming.  Don't bother with that in an interview.  Write the obvious recursive solution.  Then memoize.  That's the top down approach.  It is a lot easier to get working.

You may get challenged on that.  Here was my response the last time that I was asked about that.

*There are two approaches to dynamic programming, top down and bottom up.  The bottom up approach usually uses less memory but is harder to write.  Therefore I do the top down recursive/memoize and only go for the bottom up approach if I need the last ounce of performance.*

It is a perfectly true answer, and I got hired.

Now you may notice that tutorials about dynamic programming spend more time on bottom up.  They often even skip the top down approach.  They do that because bottom up is harder.  You have to think differently.  It does provide more efficient algorithms because you can throw away parts of that data structure that you know you won't use again.

Coming up with a working solution in an interview is hard enough already.  Don't make it harder on yourself than you need to.

**EDIT** Here is the DP solution that the interviewer thought didn't exist.

```
def find_best (floats):
    current_answers = {floats[0]: ()}
    floats = floats[1:]
    for f in floats:
        next_answers = {}
        for v, path in current_answers.iteritems():
            next_answers[v + f] = (path, '+')
            next_answers[v * f] = (path, '*')
            next_answers[v - f] = (path, '-')
            if 0 != f:
                next_answers[v / f] = (path, '/')
        current_answers = next_answers
    best_val = max(current_answers.keys())
    return (best_val, current_answers[best_val])
```

Comment: Good point. But this problem actually had no dynamic programming solution. It had a recursive solution. And it was a deceptively presented problem (it made it look like it was a dynamic programming problem). I formulated the recursive solution, but wasted a lot of time trying to "force" it to be a dynamic programming solution. Eventually he just told me that there wasn't a dynamic programming solution because there are no overlapping subproblems. So basically, I'm not sure how to identify when a recursive problem can be solved with DP or not.

Comment: @asndonsadoasndo231213 Your interviewer was wrong.  There is a DP solution.  Here is a hint.  Moving from left to right, build up a data structure of, by value that you can reach, one path to get there.  When you're done, the path to the maximum value is your answer.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm not sure I get it though. Would you mind writing brief pseudo code? I updated the question to show what my current code looks like.

Comment: @asndonsadoasndo231213 I added running code for a DP version.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks. I'll analyze it and ping you if I have further answers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the overlapping sub problem approach is something where the problem is broken down into smaller sub problems, the solutions to which when combined solve the big problem. When these sub problems exhibit an optimal sub structure DP is a good way to solve it.

The decision about what you do with a new number that you encounter has little do with the numbers you have already processed. Other than accounting for signs of course.

So I would say this is a over lapping sub problem solution but **not** a dynamic programming problem. You could use dive and conquer or evenmore straightforward recursive methods.

Initially let's forget about negative floats.

process each new float according to the following rules

1. If the new float is less than 1, insert a `/` before it
2. If the new float is more than 1 insert a `*` before it
3. If it is 1 then insert a `+`.
4. If you see a zero just don't divide or multiply

This would solve it for all positive floats.

Now let's handle the case of negative numbers thrown into the mix.

Scan the input once to figure out how many negative numbers you have.

Isolate all the negative numbers in a list, convert all the numbers whose absolute value is less than 1 to the multiplicative inverse. Then sort them by magnitude. If you have an even number of elements we are all good. If you have an odd number of elements store the head of this list in a special var , say `k`, and associate a `processed` flag with it and set the flag to `False`.

Proceed as before with some updated rules

5. If you see a negative number less than 0 but more than -1, insert a `/` divide before it
6. If you see a negative number less than -1, insert a `*` before it
7. If you see the special var and the `processed` flag is `False`, insert a `-` before it. Set `processed` to `True`.
8. There is one more optimization you can perform which is removing paris of negative ones as candidates for blanket subtraction from our initial negative numbers list, but this is just an edge case and I'm pretty sure you interviewer won't care

Now the sum is only a function of the number you are adding and not the sum you are adding to :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're proposing a set of heuristics and a linear time algorithm. How did you derive these heuristics -- through just intuition? I don't think I could do this myself.

Comment: Well I would not call it intuition as there is a finite bucket of ranges the input floats could fall into, each requiring a slightly different rule to handle them. just account for all the ranges and the range boundaries and you are done. :) . But I see why this approach could be problematic as what would one do if the number of ranges was too many to realistically write rules for, but in that event even a dynamic programming solution would be impossible as you wouldn't know what decision to make at every cell :)

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on why you think this isn't a dynamic programming problem? Is it because no solutions are able to be re-used? It bothers me because I spent like 15 minutes trying to find the "re-usable solutions".

Comment: Dynamic programming problems inherently require that decisions you make in the future hinge on decisions you have already made. That's not quite the case here. I mean technically you could make it a dp problem by using an optimal sub structure to account for negative signs, but that's overkill. How you process a new float has nothing to do with how you processed older floats in terms of magnitude. If you did a multiplication before it wouldn't change what you do now.

Comment: @Srini Even more problematic, for `(0, 1, -0.0001, -1.00000001)` you will output `0 + 1 / -0.0001 * -1.00000001` which loses to `0 - 1 / -0.0001 - -1.00000001`.

Comment: @btilly I will admit I may have messed up how to handle cases on the border of ranges. Which will require a little more fleshing out. Also I forgot to metnion an important caveat. The solution I have provided assumes the expression is evaluated one float at a time, not as a contiguous expression :)

Comment: This was the direction I had in mind when I made my comment on the question. I think it needs a little more though. To handle the case of numbers in the immediate neighborhood of 1 and -1, you would need to take the larger of two possible operators. I admit though, like @Srini, I haven't thoroughly thought out edge cases.

Comment: See, but my contention is that is not a heuristic in the strict sense, rather an algorithm with a finite number of cases to handle. Considering this was an interview question, I personally would ask the interviewer for somethings that help handle the this problem, what is the precision of the floats, etc etc, once we know that we could theoretically solve this.

Comment: @Srini I believe that if you keep track of the largest and smallest values that you can create at all points, then you will always find the right answer.  But there is no way without seeing the rest of the floats to decide if right now if the largest or the smallest is the right path to the best solution.  Heuristics based on tracking just one and then "fixing it up" are not going to work.

Comment: @Srini But furthermore, think how hard you've had to think about this problem so far.  And think how much harder it is to think under the pressure of an interview.  In an interview, is this really the kind of rabbit hole that you want to volunteer to go down?  Do the simplest thing that can work.  Don't try to be clever.  Really.

Comment: I concede that, I need some more time to go over your solution but if you can't find any violations then I guess it works :)

Comment: @btilly - that is rational advice, but balance that with the fact that often these interview problems **do** have a clever solution that has much better time complexity, and the interviewers are looking for that. But straightforward and correct does trump clever but faulty/incomplete .

Comment: @Srini I can actually prove that it works. However it is not a solution that I would ever have looked for in an interview.

Answer (score 0):

Computing max/min results for each operation from previous step. Not sure about overall correctness.

Time complexity O(n), space complexity O(n)

```
const max_value = (nums) => {
  const ops = [(a, b) => a+b, (a, b) => a-b, (a, b) => a*b, (a, b) => a/b]

  const dp = Array.from({length: nums.length}, _ => [])
  dp[0] = Array.from({length: ops.length}, _ => [nums[0],nums[0]])

  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < ops.length; j++) {

      let mx = -Infinity
      let mn = Infinity

      for (let k = 0; k < ops.length; k++) {
        if (nums[i] === 0 && k === 3) {
          // If current number is zero, removing division
          ops.splice(3, 1)
          dp.splice(3, 1)
          continue
        }

        const opMax = ops[j](dp[i-1][k][0], nums[i])
        const opMin = ops[j](dp[i-1][k][1], nums[i])
        mx = Math.max(opMax, opMin, mx)
        mn = Math.min(opMax, opMin, mn)
      }

      dp[i].push([mx,mn])
    }
  }

  return Math.max(...dp[nums.length-1].map(v => Math.max(...v)))
}


// Tests

console.log(max_value([1, 12, 3]))
console.log(max_value([1, 0, 3]))
console.log(max_value([17,-34,2,-1,3,-4,5,6,7,1,2,3,-5,-7]))
console.log(max_value([59, 60, -0.000001]))
console.log(max_value([0, 1, -0.0001, -1.00000001]))
```